# R turn off rounding number, binary classifier

Tags: r

I have some problem dealing with R. I'm trying to do logistic regression to do a classifier, but I have some problem with sigmoid function. This is the code of the sigmoid function:

```
sigmoid<-function(z){
   g=1/(1+exp(-z))
   return(g)
}
```

The problem cames up when I calculate the cost function J. R round up the Number, so if I do the `sigmoid(40)` it returns to me 1. In J when I have this part `J=......(1-y)%*%log(1-sigmoid(40))` because sigmoid function returns 1, I have log(0) that is -Inf. So it'impossible to me to do a good train to my classifier. I tried to use `options(digits=22)` but in some case I have this problem. Do you know how can I avoid this problem? With python I don't have this problem with sigmoid.

---

I post the incomplete code but to the point that i have the problem.

```
sigmoid<-function(z){
   g <- 1 / (1 + exp(-1 * z))
   return(g)
```

}

```
gradient<-function(X,y,theta,niter){
 #FITTING
 alpha<-0.001
 ep<-0.000001
 converged <- FALSE
 iter<-0
 m<-nrow(X)

 h<- sigmoid(X%*%theta)
 J<-(1/m)* t(-y)%*%log(h) - (t(1-y)%*%log(1-h))
}

#LOAD DATASET
dataset<-read.csv('candy_1.csv',sep = ',')
X<-dataset[,1:10]
y<-dataset[,11]

m<-nrow(X)
n<-ncol(X)

X<-cbind(rep(1,m),X)
X<-as.matrix(X)
theta<-sample(1:5,11,replace = TRUE) #RANDOM THETA NUMBER
thetan<-gradient(X,y,theta,10)
```

The x_dot_tetha variable have this output:

```
217.98781
2   98.42926
3   141.97051
4   166.01540 
5   168.66764
until 82 index.
```

So when i do sigmoid of this vector i have a vector of ones. When i compute J, log(1-h) became log(0). If i use the library to do logistic regression, i don't have any problem. I really can't understand if my code is correct or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I am surprised that python gives you something else.

Looking at the help page `?.Machine` we see:

> double.eps
>          the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1.

```
exp(-40)
[1] 4.248354e-18
.Machine$double.eps
[1] 2.220446e-16
```

Since `1 + exp(-40)` is indistinguishable from 1, sigmoid(40) *should* return 1.

Comment: Indeed, the only solution is then to test for a different than 1 return value to avoid problems.